# Aggregation with group and sum of nested values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using Mongo and I need to aggregate the following timeseries, grouping by `account_id` and get the sum of each nested values. For the sake of example I keep the dataset simple with only the `pub` object, but in my real collection I have other objects and values to aggregate

```
[
  {
    "account_id": 1,
    "pub": {
      "cpm": NumberDecimal("1"),
      "monthly": NumberDecimal("1.5")
    },
    "time": ISODate("2022-01-01T01:00:00.000"),
  },
  {
    "account_id": 2,
    "pub": {
      "cpm": NumberDecimal("3"),
      "monthly": NumberDecimal("3.5")
    },
    "time": ISODate("2022-01-01T01:00:00.000"),
  },
  {
    "account_id": 1,
    "pub": {
      "cpm": NumberDecimal("2"),
      "monthly": NumberDecimal("2.5")
    },
    "time": ISODate("2022-01-01T02:00:00.000"),
  },
  {
    "account_id": 2,
    "pub": {
      "cpm": NumberDecimal("4"),
      "monthly": NumberDecimal("4.5")
    },
    "time": ISODate("2022-01-01T02:00:00.000"),
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
     "_id": 1, // account_id
     "pub": {
        "cpm": 3,
        "monthly": 4
     }
  },
  {
     "_id": 2, // account_id
     "pub": {
        "cpm": 7,
        "monthly": 8
     }
  }
]
```

I have found the following two methods that works as expected, but they seems really verbose to me, especially the first. **Considering that in the real collection there are many other objects and values**.

### Method 1

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$account_id',
      pub: {
        $accumulator: {
          init: function () {
            return {
              cpm: 0,
              monthly: 0,
            };
          },
          accumulate: function (state, cpm, monthly) {
            return {
              cpm: state.cpm + cpm,
              monthly: state.monthly + monthly,
            };
          },
          accumulateArgs: [
            { $toDouble: '$pub.cpm' },
            { $toDouble: '$pub.monthly' },
          ],
          merge: function (state1, state2) {
            return {
              cpm: state1.cpm + state2.cpm,
              monthly: state1.monthly + state2.monthly,
            };
          },
          finalize: function (state) {
            return {
              cpm: state.cpm,
              monthly: state.monthly,
            };
          },
          lang: 'js',
        },
      },
    },
  }
])
```

### Method 2

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$account_id",
      "pub__cpm": {
        $sum: "$pub.cpm"
      },
      "pub__monthly": {
        $sum: "$pub.monthly"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      pub: {
        cpm: {
          "$toDouble": "$pub__cpm"
        },
        monthly: {
          "$toDouble": "$pub__monthly"
        }
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "pub__cpm",
      "pub__monthly"
    ]
  }
)]
```

It would be grate something like this

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$account_id",
    pub: {
      cpm: { $sum: "$pub.cpm" },
      monthly: { $sum: "$pub.monthly" },
    },
  }
}
```

But it throws "The field "$pub" must be an accumulator object", that's why I ended up with the first method.

There are better ways to achieve the same result? If not, which method is faster?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to format your output so instead of `$set` and `$unset` use `$project` like this

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mi1TFYadsBG)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$account_id",
      "pub__cpm": { $sum: "$pub.cpm" },
      "pub__monthly": { $sum: "$pub.monthly" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "pub": {
        "cpm": "$pub__cpm",
        "monthly": "$pub__monthly"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

After the group stage you can project the cumulative sum of the variable cpm and monthly into the `pub` using the `project` operation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$account_id",
      cpm: {
        $sum: "$pub.cpm"
      },
      monthly: {
        $sum: "$pub.monthly"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      pub: {
        cpm: "$cpm",
        monthly: "$monthly"
      }
    }
  }
])
```